# redirect or render the page if order is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render if the order is not found. The page is not redirect and I get the error:

> order not found, undefined method `shopify_name' for nil:NilClass.

My view:

```
<h1>Cancel Your Order Here</h1>

 <h3 style="color: white;">YOUR ORDER NUMBER IS <%= @order.shopify_name %></h3>
        <div id="multiple-file-preview">
          <div class="card-body">
            <% if @order.cancelled? %>
              <h5>YOUR ORDER HAS BEEN CANCELLED SUCCESSFULLY!</b> <br><br>Please contact our customer service for further information on <b>info@mrswordsmith.com</b></h5>
            <% elsif @order.scheduled? %>
              <%= link_to('Cancel',
                order_path(@order.shopify_id), class: 'btn btn-danger',
                  data: {
                    disable_with: "Order Cancelled"
                  }, method: :delete)
                %>
            <% else %>
              <h5>As you are attempting to cancel outside of the 2 hour cancellation window, please contact our customer support team</b></h5>
            <% end %>
```

my order controller

```
 def cancel

     @order = Order.where(shopify_id: params[:id]).first



  end
```

When I attempted to change the order number in the url, it gave me an error saying:

> `shopify_name' for nil:NilClass. i was wondering how to render on the
>   same page

Comment: You'll want to render or redirect in the controller, where `@order` is getting set.

Comment: @dinjas hi i've updated my cotroller

Comment: hi @dinjas thank you for you answer, that's really helpful! what if i want to render on the same page, if there's anything i can do with that?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "render on the same page". You could add a condition, `<% if @order.nil? %>...<% elsif @order.cancelled? %>...`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but...

If you're wanting to render the `cancel` view when `@order` is present, and `redirect` otherwise, your controller action would look something like this:

```
def cancel
  @order = Order.find_by(shopify_id: params[:id])

  unless @order
    flash[:alert] = 'Order not found'
    redirect_to root_path # or wherever you want them to go if order doesn't exist
  end

  # render will happen automatically, is default behavior
end
```

If you want to render a different view (with the same URL) if the order isn't found, you could do something like this:

```
def cancel
  @order = Order.find_by(shopify_id: params[:id])

  unless @order
    flash.now[:alert] = 'Order not found'
    render :new # render the new view with the cancel url
  end
end
```